# Function to return rows for a range values between columns

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers, range

I have a table with columns,ID, A and B, where I introduce some values

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 1, 6);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, 5, 8);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(3, 3, 4);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(4, 4, 5);
```

Now I´m looking for a query to tell me if a range of numbers that I pass to the query are between those values or not. So If I pass 2 and 3 (could be N numbers) I expect to see row 1 and 3.

So far the only thing that I achieve is using the IN to know If my number is in that column, but not if is higher or lower.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE A IN ('2', '3')
```

I think I would need create a function. Somebody can point me in the right direction here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all rows where the range contains the specified numbers:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  test
WHERE (2 BETWEEN A AND B) 
   OR (3 BETWEEN A AND B)
/* OR (4 BETWEEN A AND B) */
/* OR (5 BETWEEN A AND B) */
```

```
+------+------+------+
| ID   | A    | B    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    6 |
|    3 |    3 |    4 |
+------+------+------+
```

An alternate solution is to `JOIN` your table with the list of numbers:

```
SELECT DISTINCT test.*
FROM test
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 2 AS num UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 /* UNION ALL
    SELECT 4    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 */
) AS num_list ON num_list.num BETWEEN test.A AND test.B
```

Comment: mmmm the article seems like set the range of values as static.  What about if those value can be modify, we need to set first the values?. How?, with a function?. This article it´s not clear at all

Comment: (in your question) where does 2 and 3 come from? Usually you would build a SQL query such as ``$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE " . $end . " >= `A` AND `B` >= " . $start . ";``

Comment: from the client that use the application. He can use the query with a range of [N] values

Comment: range of values in the query is the "key". I think I´m gonna need to create a function

Comment: See revised answer. Basically you need to use the `BETWEEN` clause.

Answer (score -2):

Use BETWEEN

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE A BETWEEN 1 AND 3

Comment: How does that relate to the OP question - he wants to pass a list of values [(2,3) in the example] & get back the rows that contain those values (between A & B).